# Three monitors, two nvidia cards - how to craft a configuration?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors

Found numerous similar questions, either unanswered or not the "right" answer.

Configuration:

- Two NVIDIA GT 610 cards. One card has two 19" screens (one DVI, one HDMI). The other has a 17" (VGA through DVI adaptor).
- Ubuntu 16.10 amd64, nouveau driver

Problem:

Without crafting a manual configuration everything is working perfectly. `xrandr` is showing all three monitors, I can arrange them in the display settings, and all is good - except that the display (the mouse in particular) seems to be synced from the vsync of the 17" monitor - so it flickers (and even disappears at times) on the other monitors.

So I'd like to craft a manual configuration that works in the same way as I have it at the moment. Which I have almost done. Once done I can then play with various sync and cursor settings, which I don't think is possible without having a configuration to edit.

I have all three screens functional (to a certain extent) as :0.0, :0.1 and :0.2. However I'd like to have them (as I have now) all as :0, not as separate screens. `xrandr` only sees one screen - the one it is running on.

- I will not, under any circumstances, use Xinerama. It's complete pants - too slow to even play a video - so don't suggest it.

What option(s) or concepts am I missing in my xorg.conf?

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" LeftOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor2"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0a"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:3:0:0"
    Screen      0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0b"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:3:0:0"
    Screen      1
    Option      "UseDisplayDevice"   "HDMI-1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0a"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    ... more subsections ...
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card0b"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    ... more subsections ...
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor2"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    ... more subsections ...
EndSection
```

**Update:**

It looks like it's actually already running Xinerama automatically (according to `xdpyinfo`) - I thought it was being very slow :(